# How to cut range to let them have about same number of objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

For example, there are 1000 products unevenly distributed in $100~$150. And I want to cut let every price range has about same number of products.

My thought is cut it half and half recursively, something like

```
function cut(min, max, maxNum, result = []){
  if (number of min~max > maxNum) {
    mid = (max+min)/2
    cut(min, mid, maxNum)
    cut(mid+1, max, maxNum)
  } else {
    result.push(`${min}~${max}`)
  }
}
```

It works fine but the result may include the range which has much smaller than maxNum of product.

For example, $100~$112 have only 5 product while maxNum=200.

Is there any idea or better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sorting the products by price, then dividing into N ranges using Array.slice().

Once we have the ranges we can output the count, min price, max price etc for each range:

```js
const totalCount = 1000;

const maxNum = 200;
const minPrice = 100;
const maxPrice = 150;

// How many ranges to divide into
const rangeCount = totalCount / maxNum;
const rangeSize = totalCount  / rangeCount;

function getRandomPrice() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + maxPrice - minPrice)) + minPrice;
}

const products = Array.from({ length: totalCount }, (v, k) => ({ id: k + 1, name: `product ${k + 1}`, price: getRandomPrice()  }));

// Sort our products by price...
const sortedProducts = products.sort(( a, b ) => a.price - b.price);

const ranges = Array.from({ length: rangeCount }, (v, k) => sortedProducts.slice(k * rangeSize, (k + 1) * rangeSize));

console.log('Ranges:');
for(let range of ranges) {
    console.log(`Count: ${range.length} Price: $${range[0].price} -> $${range[range.length - 1].price} `)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```